# Numpy optimized reshape : 2D array to 3D

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, reshape, numpy-ndarray

I was wondering if there is a more pythonic/efficient way of reshaping my 2d-array into a 3d-array ? Here is the following working code :

```
import numpy as np
#
# Declaring the dimensions
n_ddl = 2
N = 3
n_H = n_ddl*N
#
# Typical 2D array to reshape
x_tilde_2d = np.array([[111,112,121,122,131,132],[211,212,221,222,231,232],[311,312,321,322,331,332]])
x_tilde_2d = x_tilde_2d.T
#
# Initialization of the output 3D array
x_tilde_reshaped_3d = np.zeros((N,x_tilde_2d.shape[1],n_ddl))
for i in range(0,x_tilde_2d.shape[1],1):
    x_tilde_sol = x_tilde_2d[:,i]
    x_tilde_sol_reshape = x_tilde_sol.reshape((N,n_ddl))
    for j in range(0,n_ddl,1):
        x_tilde_reshaped_3d[:,i,j] = x_tilde_sol_reshape[:,j]
```

Here is the raw expected output :

```
array([[[111., 112.],
        [211., 212.],
        [311., 312.]],

       [[121., 122.],
        [221., 222.],
        [321., 322.]],

       [[131., 132.],
        [231., 232.],
        [331., 332.]]])
```

and same output, along axis = 2 :

```
x_tilde_reshaped_3d[:,:,0] = np.array([[111., 211., 311.],
                                       [121., 221., 321.],
                                       [131., 231., 331.]])

x_tilde_reshaped_3d[:,:,1] = np.array([[112., 212., 312.],
                                       [122., 222., 322.],
                                       [132., 232., 332.]])
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So what is the expected output?

Comment: What's wrong with a simple reshape?

Comment: I just add my current / expected output to the question, sorry for that. It seems like the simple reshape proposed in the 2 answers doesn't correspond when I am doing `my-output== answer_output`

Comment: Have you looked into transposing some of the axes?

Comment: @hpaulj Can you be more specific please? I am not at ease with 3d reshaping actually, but it may be the solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply doing a [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) directly. There seems to be no need of first initializing a 3d matrix of zeros and then fill them dimension wise.

The desired order can be achieved by swapping the first and the second axis using `swapaxes(0, 1)`

EDITED Answer

```
x_tilde_2d = np.array([[111,112,121,122,131,132],[211,212,221,222,231,232],[311,312,321,322,331,332]])
x_tilde_reshaped_3d  = x_tilde_2d.reshape(N, x_tilde_2d.T.shape[1], n_ddl).swapaxes(0, 1)
print (x_tilde_reshaped_3d)
```

**Output**

```
[[[111 112]
  [211 212]
  [311 312]]

 [[121 122]
  [221 222]
  [321 322]]

 [[131 132]
  [231 232]
  [331 332]]]
```

Comment: Hi, I just added details about  expected output, as is, your solution is not working.

Comment: @Yacola: I edited my answer to get the desired answer. Let me know if you need some other help

Comment: One last thing, if i may ask, could you just modify your answer, so that the x_tilde you are reshaping is the x_tilde_2d.T that i declare ?

Comment: @Yacola: Hmm, I tried a couple of changes but it seems to not work for your transpose. My question is: Why is this additional step of transposing required?

Comment: Because it must only be seen as the way I used to generate a similar structure of the real data that I do need to reshape. I'll try to figure it out myself, otherwise I'll just transpose my original data set before applying to it your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
In [337]: x=np.array([[111,112,121,122,131,132],[211,212,221,222,231,232],[311,3
     ...: 12,321,322,331,332]])
In [338]: x.shape
Out[338]: (3, 6)
In [339]: x
Out[339]: 
array([[111, 112, 121, 122, 131, 132],
       [211, 212, 221, 222, 231, 232],
       [311, 312, 321, 322, 331, 332]])
```

The only reshape that keeps the last dimension in the right order is:

```
In [340]: x.reshape(3,3,2)
Out[340]: 
array([[[111, 112],
        [121, 122],
        [131, 132]],

       [[211, 212],
        [221, 222],
        [231, 232]],

       [[311, 312],
        [321, 322],
        [331, 332]]])
```

Now just swap the first two dimensions:

```
In [341]: x.reshape(3,3,2).transpose(1,0,2)
Out[341]: 
array([[[111, 112],
        [211, 212],
        [311, 312]],

       [[121, 122],
        [221, 222],
        [321, 322]],

       [[131, 132],
        [231, 232],
        [331, 332]]])
```

Comment: Perhaps also worth adding that one can also use `swapaxes(0,1)` as an alternative to `transpose(1,0,2)`

Comment: Great thanks @hpaulj, I am more used to `.T` transpose for 2D arrays, I ll try to look closer at this wonderful `numpy.transpose()` function. Have a nice day.

Comment: I tend to use `.transpose` over `swapaxes` because it's more expressive.  It is harder to intuit, but I think the learning curve is worth it.